# How can I protect my D3 data CSV from download by my users?

Tags: javascript, apache, d3.js

I have a D3JS visualization that's working by reading in a CSV file with the d3.csv method. Up until now, I've been storing my d3 code and the CSV in the same subdirectory, under web root. Ideally, though, I'd like to protect the CSV from download by users using only their browsers. As of now, they can go through my JS code and discover the location, then just download it.

I tried to create a subdirectory under document root and reference it in my D3 code with something like "../d3data/mydata.csv". For some reason, D3 still interprets this as being under public_html.

All of this stuff is being hosted in a subdirectory on a Wordpress site, so I'm leery of changing any of my central .php files or .htaccess. Any help?

Comment: If your script can download it, users can download it.  The only way around it would be to do all the calculation on the server and only have users download the final SVG.

Comment: One way would be to encode your file with a header and retrieve it with an Ajax request. You don't necessarily need the d3.csv method.